# Space between two consecutive headings with titlesec option largestsep

Tags: spacing, sectioning, titlesec

To format headings I am using the `titlesec` package. I need 12 pt space before each heading and 6 pt after. If there are consecutive headings (i.e. heading directly followed by subheading) I need 12 pt space between them. Therefore, I use the package option `largestsep`. However, the space between two headings is more than 12 pt. Am I missing something?

> Quote from the titlesec documentation: "By default, when there are two consecutive titles the aftersep space from the first one is used between them. […] With largestsep the largest of them is used.”)

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[largestsep]{titlesec}
\titlespacing {\section} {0pt} {12pt} {6pt}
\titlespacing {\subsection} {0pt} {12pt} {6pt}
\begin{document}
\section{Section}
\subsection{Subsection}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are right in saying this doesn't work.  It looks like a bug to me.  Adding `\unskip` after the first title restores the behaviour, removing a spurious vertical skip of zero size that is inserted in the output and preventing the internal `\addvspace` having any effect.  I don't know where this extra zero space is generated.

In the code below, `\showoutput` tells us that the `\unskip` variant results in

```
...\glue 6.0
...\glue -6.0
...\glue 12.0
```

as desired, whereas without the `\unskip` we get

```
...\glue 6.0
...\glue 0.0
...\glue 12.0
```

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[largestsep]{titlesec}
\titlespacing{\section}{0pt}{12pt}{6pt}
\titlespacing{\subsection}{0pt}{12pt}{6pt}

\begin{document}
\showoutput
\section{Section}\unskip
\subsection{Subsection}
\lipsum[1]
\section{Section}
\subsection{Subsection}
\lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```

Update: thanks to Ruixi Zhang the source of the zero skip has been identified.  The `titlesec` code uses LaTeX's `\vspace` which is essentially the required `\vskip` followed by a second zero `\vskip`.  Changing `\vspace` to `\vskip` in the appropriate internal function gives the desired behaviour.  Here is a local patch via `etoolbox`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage[largestsep]{titlesec}
\titlespacing{\section}{0pt}{12pt}{6pt}
\titlespacing{\subsection}{0pt}{12pt}{6pt}

\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\ttl@straight@ii}{\vspace{\@tempskipb}}{\vskip\@tempskipb}{}{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\showoutput
\section{Section}
\subsection{Subsection}
\lipsum[1]
\section{Section}
\subsection{Subsection}
\lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```

producing glue sequence

```
...\glue 6.0
...\glue -6.0
...\glue 12.0
```

as wished and resulting in

[image]

Comment: Thx! Any idea for a global workaround?

Comment: Not currently, I have not yet tracked down the source of the extra zero skip.

Comment: any new on this?

Comment: Sorry, no.  Have you tried sending a bug report to the `titlesec` author?

Comment: I've tried twice but got no response.

Comment: @AndrewSwann The extra zero skip comes from `\vspace` since LaTeX2e kernel defines `\vspace{#1}` to expand to `... \vskip #1 \vskip\z@skip ...`

Comment: @Janine Bug report filed along with proposed fixes: https://github.com/jbezos/titlesec/issues/27

Comment: @RuixiZhang Well spotted.  Local patch solution added to answer.